# How to make Amazon Elastic Beanstalk https only?

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for my JSP web deployment.
I want my application should be run only on HTTPS.
I have also configured load scheduler to listen HTTPS request as well.
But i am not able to find a way where it will become HTTPS only.
I tried to configure my EBS server(using PUTTY & my machine ip i edited server.xml & web.xml so that each request will become HTTPS as per tutorial http://www.itworld.com/development/79351/how-configure-tomcat-always-require-https)
But when i done this then EBS server health gone down(red).
Also i noticed when load on application grows beyond threshold then new instance is created & when load gets down then old instance will be deleted & new one is preserver so please somebody tell me how to deal with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post you ELB configuration details and your Tomcat configs?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in [Configuring HTTPS for your AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html):

> You can configure your AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment to use HTTPS for your application. Configuring HTTPS ensures traffic encryption for client connections to the load balancer.

The entire process is slightly involved, *you will need to do the following high-level steps*:

> 1. Create a custom domain with your DNS provider.
> 2. Create and upload an SSL certificate to AWS Identity and Access Management (AWS IAM).
> 3. Update your Elastic Beanstalk environment to use HTTPS.

Specifically, section *Step 3: Update Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment to Use HTTPS* outlines how to configure you load balancer as desired once your custom domain and SSL certificate are in place:

> After you receive your Amazon Resources Name (ARN), you need to update your load balancer configuration settings in your Elastic Beanstalk environment with the following information:
>
> - HTTP port — set this port to **OFF** or **80**
> - HTTPS port — set this port to **443** or **8443**

Comment: I've managed to accomplish all of these steps through the AWS console, but when I try to add these configurations via saved-configs the secured port is not enabled. Do you have any reference for how to properly write these configs? I've tried to use the ones in this link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html. I know the environment is created with these configs since the certificate is being configured and the 80 port is closed, but the 443 port remains disabled as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to make a standard Elastic Beanstalk SSL only or private / locked down by IP.

This is because they used Elastic Load Balancers which are inherently pulbic.

Recently they released [VPC support for Elastic Beanstalks](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk/8426458343844669), which allows you restrict access and to use private load balancers.

Alternatively you could setup your own HAProxy or use OpsWorks to setup HAProxy